# JavaScript find element by text

Tags: javascript, html, xpath

I'm in an environment don't have jQuery.
I want to find the tag or tags that contain certain text.
The DOM looks like this:

```
<div>
    <div>
        <h2>contain certain text</h2>
    </div>
    <div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I was using XPath to locate this div.

```
var linkBox = document.evaluate(
    '//h2[contains(text(),"certain text")]/../..', 
    document, 
    null, 
    XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE, 
    null )
```

It works fine. Until I found out IE doesn't support XPath in document. 
Now I'm doing `getElementsByTagname('h2')` and then enumerate the whole set to check the innterText.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: If you have to support IE, no, there's no other way than to actually check the text of each element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What's the lowest version of IE that you're concerned with?

You may be able to use [Array.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to help narrow down your search. Here's an example:

**HTML**

```
<div>
    <div>
        <h2>contain certain text</h2>
        <h2>contain certain text</h2>
        <h2>YAY</h2>
        <h2>contain certain text</h2>
    </div>
    <div>
        <h2>contain certain text</h2>
        <h2>contain certain text</h2>
        <h2>contain certain text</h2>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
//turn nodelist into an array
//feel free to use getElementsByTagName or something similar here
var h2 = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll("h2"));

//Array of matches
var matches = h2.filter(filterElements);

console.log(matches);

//Filter Function
function filterElements(element){
    return element.textContent === "YAY";
}
```

There's a polyfill Array.filter as well on the MDN page.

[**EXAMPLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/gF6xL/)

Comment: +1 with a sidenote that `getElementsByTagName` is faster than `querySelectorAll`, and also that you can just call `Array.prototype.filter.call(collection, filterElements)`, making the call to `slice()` redundant.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It's very useful. but unfortunately I need support IE8 as the latest IE on xp. And the polyfill is basically doing the same thing I'm doing. Still it's good to know.

Answer (score 0):

Even if you are using a library like XPath, it doesn't do magic and it is probable that it is doing the same as you are doing.

I think your question "is there a better way" refers to the time to do the task. I would suggest you to do some tests and compare the time taken using your method and using the library method.
Using the google console it will be easy to test: https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/console#measuring-how-long-something-takes