# A function to remove a div element that contains specific text in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I've written a simple code that takes text from the input field, stores it as a string in an array and creates a div with that same text every time the "add" button is pressed.

Then there's a "remove" button, that removes the item from array if the input matches the item in the array.

I need a function to remove the previously created div with the same text inside as the current input.

E.g. if I type "book1" press "add" - array gets 'book1' as a first item and a div "book1" is created, "book2", "book3" and so on. If I type 'book2' and press remove,  it gets removed from the array and a respective div should be removed.

That last function I just can't figure out.

```js
let addBtn = document.getElementById("add-btn");
let removeBtn = document.getElementById("rmv-btn");
let bookArray = [];
addBtn.addEventListener("click", addBook);
removeBtn.addEventListener("click", removeBook);
let innerDiv = document.body.newDiv.innerHTML

function addBook() {
  newBook = document.getElementById("input").value;
  if (newBook != '') {
    bookArray.push(newBook);
    addElement();
    clear();
    console.log(bookArray);
  } else {
    clear();

    console.log(bookArray);
  }
}

function removeBook() {
  inputBook = document.getElementById("input").value;
  for (i = 0; i < bookArray.length; i++) {
    if (inputBook.toString() === bookArray[i].toString()) {
      bookArray.splice([i], 1);
      console.log(bookArray);
      removeElement()
      return;
    } else {
      clear();
    }
  }
  console.log(bookArray);
}

function clear() {
  document.getElementById("input").value = "";
}

function addElement() {
  let newDiv = document.createElement("div");
  newDiv.innerHTML = newBook;

  my_div = document.getElementById("mydiv");
  document.body.appendChild(newDiv, my_div);
}

function removeElement() { 
   alert("this bit needs working out");//???
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="input" />
<button id="add-btn">Add</button>
<button id="rmv-btn">Remove</button>
<div id="mydiv"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why not just include a 'remove' icon with each entry? Users can then just click that to remove the item they need instead of having to re-type the name again. Also, it's a much simpler pattern to build the array from the entries when it's actually going to be used, instead of maintaining additions/deletions as they are made.

Comment: There's a [tag:jquery] solution [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12957886/find-div-by-text-and-delete-text) but your current code is not using [tag:jquery] and you shouldn't add it just for this feature.

Comment: There's a [tag:javascript] solution [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25073782/2181514) but it's only partial as it helps you find the elements.  You can call `.remove()` on an element to remove it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change how you are adding the div because it adding it outside and not as a child of my_div

```
let addBtn = document.getElementById("add-btn");
    let removeBtn = document.getElementById("rmv-btn");
    let bookArray = [];
    addBtn.addEventListener("click", addBook);
    removeBtn.addEventListener("click", removeBook);
    
    
    function addBook() {
      newBook = document.getElementById("input").value;
      if (newBook != '') {
        bookArray.push(newBook);
        addElement();
        clear();
        console.log(bookArray);
      } else {
        clear();
    
        console.log(bookArray);
      }
    }
    
    function removeBook() {
      inputBook = document.getElementById("input").value;
      for (i = 0; i < bookArray.length; i++) {
        if (inputBook.toString() === bookArray[i].toString()) {
          bookArray.splice([i], 1);
          console.log(bookArray);
          removeElement(i);
          return;
        } else {
          clear();
        }
      }
      console.log(bookArray);
    }
    
    function clear() {
      document.getElementById("input").value = "";
    }
    
    function addElement() {    
      let newDiv = document.createElement("div");
      // count number of children in mydiv
      let count = document.getElementById("mydiv").childElementCount;
    
      // add an id
    
      newDiv.id = 'mydiv-' + count;
      newDiv.innerHTML = newBook;
    
      my_div = document.getElementById("mydiv");
      my_div.appendChild(newDiv, my_div);
    }
    
    function removeElement(el) { 
       // remove html element from dom
        let my_div = document.getElementById("mydiv");
        my_div.removeChild(my_div.childNodes[el]);
    }
```

Comment: CMartins, thank you. That was it. I didn't think of .childElementCount. Now it works exactly as it should.

Answer (score 1):

A workaround to remove book by the `input` value by user:

Modify the `addElement` function to:

```
function addElement() {
  let newDiv = document.createElement("div");
  newDiv.innerHTML = newBook;
  newDiv.setAttribute('data-book-name', newBook); //new added line | setting data attribute

  my_div = document.getElementById("mydiv");
  document.body.appendChild(newDiv, my_div);
}
```

`removeElement` will be:

```
function removeElement() { 
   document.querySelector('[data-book-name="'+ newBook +'"]')?.remove();
}
```

But this will remove first book in the DOM. If you want to remove all books with same name use:

```
function removeElement() { 
   var books = document.querySelectorAll('[data-book-name="'+ newBook +'"]');
   if(books.length == 0) return;
   books.forEach(x => x.remove())
}
```

Comment: Thank you, Qazi, for your answer. It still doesn't remove the element from the input.

Comment: "*doesn't remove the element* from the input."?  You mean `document.getElementById("input").value = "";`?

Comment: @freedomn-m is right if you want to clear the input use `document.getElementById("input").value = "";`

Comment: No, I meant it doesn't remove the div of the element typed into the input field.